# Attaching a PDF to an email in Appengine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How do I attach a PDF sitting in the base directory of my Appengine app to an email message?
What `should message.attachments` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields), the attachments field is a list of tuples in which the first element is the filename and the second the byte string representing the file. So you just need to read the pdf:

```
pdf_contents = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'yourpdf.pdf')).read()
```

this assumes that your pdf and the python file are in the same folder. And then

```
attachments = [('yourpdf.pdf', pdf_contents)]
```